# view top changes when pushed to another view and pop again

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview

I am using a scrollview in which I am having 2 views inside. when I have pushed it in different view controller and again pop it, the top constraint changes its position.

I have used both-

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

 self.scrollViewGiftCardCredit.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

but didn't get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the viewController that you pushed the scrollView in

```
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.TopConstraint.constant = 0

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```